# Get rid of circular dependency in Angular

Tags: angular

In my angular app I have two modules, core module and shared module. Core module contains all singleton services, interceptors and all. Shared module has all shared components, pipes, directions. Structure looks something like this -

```
Core ->
  --- /Services
      --- title.service.ts
      --- analytics.service.ts
      --- logger.service.ts
      --- confirm-dialog.service.ts
      --- index.ts
core.module.ts


Shared ->
  --- /components
      --- direction-map
      --- confirm-dialog
      --- index.ts
shared.module.ts
```

When I am trying to user logger service in shared map component this waring in console-
[image]

**Core Module**

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule, Optional, SkipSelf } from '@angular/core';
import { EnsureModuleLoadedOnceGuard } from './ensureModuleLoadedOnceGuard';
import { AjaxService } from './http';
import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication';
import { HTTPInterceptorProvider } from './interceptors';
import {
    TitleService,
    LoggerService,
    AnalyticsService,
    ConfirmationDialogService
} from './services';

const PROVIDERS = [
    AjaxService,
    TitleService,
    LoggerService,
    AnalyticsService,
    AuthenticationService,
    ConfirmationDialogService
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule, HttpClientModule],
    exports: [RouterModule, HttpClientModule],
    providers: [...PROVIDERS, HTTPInterceptorProvider]
})
export class CoreModule extends EnsureModuleLoadedOnceGuard {
    constructor(
        @Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: CoreModule,
        _titleService: TitleService
    ) {
        super(parentModule);
        _titleService.init();
    }
}
```

**Shared Module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import {
    DirectionMapComponent,
    ConfirmDialogComponent
} from '@shared/components';

import { ShortNumberPipe, ... } from '@shared/pipes';

import { DigitOnlyDirective, ... } from '@shared/directives';

const MODULES = [CommonModule];

const PIPES = [
    ShortNumberPipe, ...
];

const DIRECTIVES = [
    DigitOnlyDirective, ...
];

const SHARED_COMPONENTS = [DirectionMapComponent, ConnectionStatusComponent];
const ENTRY_COMPONENTS = [ConfirmDialogComponent];

@NgModule({
    imports: [...MODULES],
    declarations: [
        ...ENTRY_COMPONENTS,
        ...SHARED_COMPONENTS,
        ...CUSTOM_PIPES,
        ...DIRECTIVES
    ],
    exports: [...SHARED_COMPONENTS, ...MODULES, ...PIPES, ...DIRECTIVES],
    entryComponents: [...ENTRY_COMPONENTS]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

**App Module**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        CoreModule,
        TemplateModule,
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

**ConfirmationDialogService**

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { ConfirmDialogComponent } from '@shared/components';
import { BsModalService, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { Observable, Observer } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class ConfirmationDialogService {
    constructor(private _injector: Injector) {}

    private bsModalRef!: BsModalRef;
    private dialogModalConfig = {
        backdrop: true,
        animated: true,
        ignoreBackdropClick: false,
        keyboard: true
    };

    private get _bs() {
        return this._injector.get(BsModalService);
    }

    confirm(
        title: string,
        message: string,
        options: string[]
    ): Observable<string> {
        const initialState = {
            title: title,
            message: message,
            options: options,
            answer: ''
        };
        this.bsModalRef = this._bs.show(ConfirmDialogComponent, {
            initialState
        });

        return new Observable<string>(this.getConfirmSubscriber());
    }

    private getConfirmSubscriber() {
        return (observer: any) => {
            const subscription = this._bs.onHidden.subscribe(
                (reason: string) => {
                    observer.next(this.bsModalRef.content.answer);
                    observer.complete();
                }
            );

            return {
                unsubscribe() {
                    subscription.unsubscribe();
                }
            };
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem happening because of BsModalService. When I am BsModalService inside ConfirmationDialogService getting this error.

I have tried with injector but still the same error.

Comment: Can I get any help on this?